# Insert a html link next to form text field using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I have a form which contains first name and last name..

They can be cloned/duplicated by clicking "Add more" link.

Here is the code..

```
<form>
    <p class="clone">
    First name: <input type="text" name="fname[]" value=""><br>
Last name: <input type="text" name="lname[]" value=""><br>
    </p>
   </form>
<a href="#" class="add" rel=".clone">Add More</a>
```

Here is the jsfiddle demo http://jsfiddle.net/d6mYr/
    ​

Now i would like insert this link next to **last name** text form field.

```
<a href="#">Example</a>
```

Currently my form doesn't have class attributes in the form fields. It has only name attributes.

So can anyone help me to add that link automatically using jquery?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without using that relCopy plugin

```
$(function() {
    var exampleLink = $('<a href="#">Example</a>')
    exampleLink.insertAfter('input[name="lname\[\]"]')

    $('a.add').click(function() {
        var removeLink = $('<a href="#" />').text('Remove').click(function() {
            $(this).parent().slideUp(function() {
                $(this).remove();
            })
        });

        var new_row = $('.clone:first').clone();
        new_row.append(removeLink)
        new_row.appendTo($(this).prev());
    });
});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/d6mYr/3/

Comment: Excellent.. But I want that link in default fields too. In your fiddle it appears only in cloned fields. Can you fix it? Thanks

Comment: And one more thing, as of now it appears outside the fieldset. But i need it only next to last name..

Comment: do you want to add that to default fields after the user clicks on add?

Comment: it is actually next to last name field in the DOM

Comment: I accidently pasted that link it should have been this http://jsfiddle.net/d6mYr/3/

Comment: Oh, thanks. One more fix please. can you tell me how to change the code for multidimensional array like  user[name][1][1],user[name][2][1],user[name][3][1].. etc..? I should change this line right?.. `exampleLink.insertAfter('input[name="lname\[\]"]')`.  Is it `exampleLink.insertAfter('input[name="user\[name\]\[\]\[\]"]')` ?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are already adding the link, but it's positioned below 'first name'. Try removing the `BR` tag after last name input:

```
<form>
    <p class="clone">
    First name: <input type="text" name="fname[]" value=""><br>
    Last name: <input type="text" name="lname[]" value="">
    </p>
</form>
<a href="#" class="add" rel=".clone">Add More</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add the following before your `relCopy` function call:

```
  var exampleLink = '<a href="#">Example</a>';
  $('input[name="lname[]"]').last().after(exampleLink);
```